# Motorized tripod head with zoom

Tags: camcorder

I am looking into a motorized tripod head to use with a standard camcorder and am wondering what people normally do for zoom?

The camera I am using is a [Canon HF R56](http://www.canon.co.uk/For_Home/Product_Finder/Camcorders/High_Definition_HD/LEGRIA_HF_R56/). (I am not interested in the CT-V1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cameras which support external control of zoom, focus, and iris normally have a port for this purpose.  LANC is the most common, but it appears that your camera doesn't have a LANC port.  According to the documentation to which you linked, the camera supports "remote control & streaming" via WiFi.  If it is at all possible to control your camera's zoom remotely, then it seems that WiFi would be the most likely method.